# Helm: variables in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a need to use variables inside of `values.yaml` file:

```
app:
    version: 1.0

my_app1:
    tag: {{ .app.version }} <- version taken from appVersion. In my case tag == version
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app:
    version: 1.0

my_app1:
    tag:  {{ .Values.app.version }}

{{ .Values.app | first | default .Values.app.version }}
```

You can also try this `EDIT - 2`

```
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.app }}
       {{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: how do you know .app.version is an array?

Comment: if there is more thn one value and he want to print

Comment: I've tried it before posted the question - the result is: ): error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.app.version":interface {}(nil)}

Comment: There were more spaces than 2 spaces.